# Title:Passing a variable value to function in R

Tags: r

Thanks in advance for you help.
I'm running a function, and trying to use the variable value in some of the naming assignments in the function that will call a .xts table.

```
PassValue <- function(dfX) {
    start <- as.Date("2019-01-01")
    end <- as.Date("2020-10-01")
    dfNew = paste0("A1_",dfX)
    assign( dfNew ,getSymbols( Symbols = dfX, src='yahoo',from = start, to = end, auto.assign=FALSE ),envir = .GlobalEnv)
    weeklyReturn(dfNew)
}
```

When I call the function... PassValue("GS"), it returns the following:

```
PassValue("GS")
Error in try.xts(x) : 
  Error in UseMethod("as.xts") :   no applicable method for 'as.xts' applied to an object of class "character"
Called from: try.xts(x)
```

Again, I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the symbol "A1_GS" should return but your assign function needs to be a named object of prices for weeklyReturn().

```
PassValue <- function(dfX) {
    start <- as.Date("2019-01-01")
    end <- as.Date("2020-10-01")
    dfNew = paste0("A1_",dfX)
    dat_val<-assign( dfNew ,getSymbols( Symbols = dfX, src='yahoo',from = start, to = end, auto.assign=FALSE ),envir = .GlobalEnv)
    weeklyReturn(dat_val)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for question.  Ideally, A1_GS is the "open high low close volume" of GS (Goldman Sachs), but could pass any stock, generating an .xts object for all stocks that I send the PassValue function.  I'm going to be calling the .xts object to analyze during this function and later after the function ends.   Would prefer to access the .xts object via a parameter call instead of a hard coded name.